# adaboost regressor taking very long time

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, decision-tree, adaboost

I'm trying to do adaboost for my time series forecasting with following code

```
df_store = pd.read_pickle('CA_2.pkl')  
snap_feature  = ['snap_'+store.split('_')[0]]
selected_columns = [column for column in df_store.columns if '7' not in column and 'rolling' not in column and 'snap' not in column and 'state' not in column]
df_store = df_store[df_store['d']>90][selected_columns+snap_feature]
x_train,y_train = df_store[df_store['d']<1914].drop(['id','store_id','sales_usd','daily_avg_sales_unit','is_weekday','units_sold'],axis=1),df_store[df_store['d']<1914]['units_sold']
x_valid,y_valid = df_store[(df_store['d']>1913) & (df_store['d']<1942)].drop(['id','store_id','sales_usd','daily_avg_sales_unit', 'is_weekday','units_sold'],axis=1),df_store[(df_store['d']>1913) & (df_store['d']<1942)]['units_sold']
x_test = df_store.loc[(df_store['d']>1941 )].drop(['id','store_id','sales_usd','daily_avg_sales_unit','is_weekday','units_sold'],axis=1)
print("Train X and y shape")
print(x_train.shape,y_train.shape)    
print("Validation X and y shape")
print(x_valid.shape,y_valid.shape)
ada_boost_reg = 
AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=8),n_estimators=600,random_state=42)
ada_boost_reg.fit(x_train.values,y_train.values)
val_pred = ada_boost_reg.predict(x_valid.values)
```

The shape of the train and validation set is

```
Train X and y shape
(5558327, 39) (5558327,)
Validation X and y shape
(85372, 39) (85372,)
```

I'm running it for more than 10 hours still I'm not seeing any output, is that internally does any hyper parameter tuning? If so how to disable it?

And I'm also training with depth 1, and it's taking 1:45 hours and I have to train like that for 10 datasets.

```
ada_boost_reg = AdaBoostRegressor(base_estimator=DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=1),n_estimators=800,learning_rate=0.05,random_state=42)
    ada_boost_reg.fit(x_train.values,y_train.values)
```

Comment: It does not; but boosting 600 tress of 8-depth on a 5.5M samples dataset is not a light job...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, Now I'm doing it on depth=1(default decision stump) and It's still taking 1.45 hours to train, can we some how faster the train time please check my updated code.

Comment: AdaBoost tree construction is sequential, meaning each of your 600 trees has to be created one by one. Within the scikit-learn world, you either need to use fewer trees, less data, or a faster base estimator algorithm if you need this to go faster. One way to make your base algorithm faster is to change the DecisionTree parameters. Explore the documentation.